# Use cyrillic characters in tikzposter

Tags: cyrillic, tikzposter

I have a poster, created with `tikzposter`. The code, used for it, is here:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm,
blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}

\usetheme{Desert}
\usecolorstyle{Sweden}

\title{Title}
\author{Authors}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle 
    \begin{columns}
    \column{0.7}
    \block{Introduction}{
        Text here
    }
    \column{0.3}
    \block{Picture}{
        Picture here
    }
    \end{columns}

\end{document}
```

It compiles normally:
[image: Poster]

Now, I want to translate it to Russian. I'm adding font, encoding and babel packages like so:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm,
blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}

\usetheme{Desert}
\usecolorstyle{Sweden}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\title{Название}
\author{Авторы}
\institute{Институт}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle 
    \begin{columns}
    \column{0.7}
    \block{Введение}{
        Текст здесь
    }
    \column{0.3}
    \block{Рисунок}{
        Рисунок здесь
    }
    \end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Now, it returns the error `! Corrupted NFSS tables`.
I have `texlive-full texlive-lang-cyrillic texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra` installed.
Can you help me with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate problems.

1. The `tikzposter` class loads the obsolete package `ae`
2. The Cyrillic fonts (LA fonts) are generated at discrete steps; the class requires fonts as big as 51.69pt, which makes Metafont choke for “enormous number”.

Here's a possible solution, by making the font selection scheme to scale the biggest available font size.

```
% we don't want ae.sty
\expandafter\def\csname ver@ae.sty\endcsname{}

\documentclass[
  25pt,
  a0paper,
  portrait,
  margin=0mm,
  innermargin=15mm,
  blockverticalspace=15mm,
  colspace=15mm,
  subcolspace=8mm
]{tikzposter}

\usetheme{Desert}
\usecolorstyle{Sweden}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xEC@family}[5]{%
  \DeclareFontShape{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  {<-5.5>#50500
   <5.5-6.5>#50600
   <6.5-7.5>#50700
   <7.5-8.5>#50800
   <8.5-9.5>#50900
   <9.5-10.5>#51000
   <10.5-11.5>#51095
   <11.5-13>#51200
   <13-16>#51440
   <16-18>#51728
   <18-21>#52074
   <21-26.88>#52488
   <26-32>#52986
   <32->#53583}{}}
\DeclareFontFamily{T2A}{cmr}{}
\xEC@family{T2A}{cmr}{m}{n}{larm}
\xEC@family{T2A}{cmr}{m}{sl}{lasl}
\xEC@family{T2A}{cmr}{m}{it}{lati}
\xEC@family{T2A}{cmr}{m}{sc}{lacc}
\xEC@family{T2A}{cmr}{bx}{n}{labx}
\xEC@family{T2A}{cmr}{b}{n}{larb}
\xEC@family{T2A}{cmr}{bx}{it}{labi}
\xEC@family{T2A}{cmr}{bx}{sl}{labl}
\xEC@family{T2A}{cmr}{bx}{sc}{laxc}
\xEC@family{T2A}{cmr}{m}{ui}{laui}
\makeatother

\title{Название}
\author{Авторы}
\institute{Институт}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle 
    \begin{columns}
    \column{0.7}
    \block{Введение}{
        Текст здесь
    }
    \column{0.3}
    \block{Рисунок}{
        Рисунок здесь
    }
    \end{columns}

\end{document}
```